# C: Binary Search for Char (name)

Tags: c, search, binary, char

I have a problem in understanding how to binary search for char. I have to search for a name of a smartphone. I have this:

```
typedef struct smartphone {
    char name[50];
    double weight;
} smartphone;

smartphone smartphone[50];
char smartphone_searched = "Xperia U";
```

So, i have to make a binary search for the name "Xperia U". Any suggestions?

Comment: It is not possible to hold a string in a char variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to sort your array (to use binary search) according to smartphones' names like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<49; i++)
{
    int minIndex = i;
    for(int j=i+1; j<50; j++)
    {
        if(strcmp(smartphone[i].name, smartphone[j].name) > 0)
            minIndex = j;
    }
    smartphone tmp = smartphone[i];
    smartphone[i] = smartphone[minIndex];
    smartphone[minIndex] = tmp;
}
```

Then, you'll use binary search logic using strcmp to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Error Correction :**

```
 char smartphone_searched[50] = "Xperia U";
```

instead of

```
char smartphone_searched = "Xperia U";
```

Then sort your array of structures using qsort() as:

```
static int cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
        char* y1 = ((const struct smartphone*)p1)->name;
        char* y2 = ((const struct smartphone*)p2)->name;

        if (strcmp(y1,y2) > 0)
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;
}
```

and then

```
qsort(smartphone, 50, sizeof(*smartphone), cmp);
```

And then use binary sort on the array

```
int i=0;
int j=49;
while(i<j)
{
    mid=i+j;
    if(strcmp(smartphone[mid],smartphone_searched)==0)
    {
          printf("Found\n);
          return 0;
    }
    else if(strcmp(smartphone[mid],smartphone_searched)>0)
           i=mid+1;
    else
           j=mid-1;
}
```